# Direct Mapped Cache, textbook excerpt clarification, identifying block field

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-hardware, memory-access, memory-allocation

I have an excerpt from my textbook concerning direct mapped cache that I would like further clarification on, the text reads.....

"Consider the following example: Assume memory consists of 2^14 words, cache has 16 blocks, and each block has 8 words. From this we determine that memory has 2^14/2^13 = 2^11 blocks.

We know that each main memory address requires 14 bits. 
Of this 14-bit address field, the rightmost 3 bits reflect the word field (we need 3 bits to uniquely identify one of 8 words in a block). 
We need 4 bits to select a specific block in cache, so the block field consists of the middle 4 bits.

The remaining 7 bits make up the tag field."

My questions are:

Where does the 2^13 come from when they calculated how many blocks in the first paragraph?

How did they go about identifying that the block field should contain 4 bits?
Is this because the cache has 16 blocks and 2^4 is 16?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The arithmetic doesn't make sense.  2^14/2^3=2^11, not 2^13.  2^3 is the eight words (per block).

Comment: 2^13 : Probably a typo, should be 2^3 = 8 words per block. 4bits : Yes, this is because you need 4 address bits to select among 16 blocks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag, index and offset of associative cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33818/tag-index-and-offset-of-associative-cache)