# Direct-mapping cache question

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Say I have the following memory scheme:

> Data bus: 8 bit
>
> Main Memory Store: 256 Byte
>
> Cache Store : 32 Byte
>
> Block Size : 4 Byte

How would I go about listing the assigned bits for tag,offset and block number for location 12?

I think the right answer is 12 is binary is 00001100 since we have 8-bit representation. Then the first 4-bits would be line number and block number and the last 4 would be the offset? Is this correct? If not can anyone explain why?

I got this question wrong on homework and my TA is not responding to my questions.

My line of thinking is that each memory location saved in a cache is made of 3 components, the tag (which is what the cache uses to recognize it), the index (the location in cache that it is stored), the offset(tells the ram which offset hold the value).

Now in tag + index = baselocation and baselocation + offset = the address we want in main mem.

First off to calculate the offset it should 2^b where b = linesize. In direct mapping line size = block size which is 4. So the lower 4 bits are my offset.

Next the index which is the power of 2 that is needed to uniquely address memory. Since the cache total is 32. We need 2^x = 32 which is 5.

Lastly the tag is total# of bits - (offset + index) = -1 because 8 -9 which I know is inherently wrong.

This leads me to my previous answer above for location 12. Since it is 8-bits the lower 4 must be my offset leaving the upper 4 for my tag and index.

Guess that's why I got it wrong. But what is the right answer? And how do you solve these types of problems?

Comment: It is, literally, your TA's job to respond to this kind of question. If they haven't responded within a reasonable amount of time, you need to take this up with the class's teacher.

Comment: I've already sent him an email but I would still like to know why my answer is wrong.

Comment: It is not correct, you should explain how you think you should calculate these numbers so you can be corrected properly.

Comment: @harold thank you. I have done as you've recommended. If you have any more follow up queries let me know and I can edit them in. After typing out my steps verbatim I feel like my index is wrong somehow. Like maybe it should be smaller?

Comment: Offset calculation is the wrong way around. Index calculation ignores line size.

Comment: @harold wrong way around? What do you mean?  Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The number of bytes you can address with b bits is 2^b, so given that you must address 4 bytes, you have to solve 2^b=4, not take 2^4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49628/discussion-between-kaz-rodgers-and-harold).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag, index and offset of associative cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33818/tag-index-and-offset-of-associative-cache)