# Calculate number of cache lines per set or cache size

Tags: cpu-cache, caching

How can I calculate the number of cache lines per set or the cache size with the given information?

- m (number of physical address bits): 32
- C (cache size): unknown
- B (Block size in bytes): 32
- E (number of lines per set): unknown
- S (number of cache sets): 32
- t (tag bits): 22
- s (set index bits): 5
- b (block offset bits): 5
- associativity unknown

Since we can calculate C with C=B*E*S or E with E=C/(B*S). I just need to know how to calculate C or E.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it with the help of tag, index, and offset bits. Read about it [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33818/tag-index-and-offset-of-associative-cache).

Comment: I think it's not possible. Assume E=32=C/B (fully associative cache) then C is 2^15. Assume E=1 (direct mapped cache) then C is 2^10. Please show me how you would calculate it.