# How to determine index being access in memory

Tags: computer-architecture

Having 4GB byte addressable main memory in 32-bit system divided into block of size 1024 bytes. 
If processor wants to access a memory location 0xFC347004. Corresponding block is found in cache.

Which index, within this block, will be accessed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag, index and offset of associative cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33818/tag-index-and-offset-of-associative-cache)

Comment: no, it's much simpler question

Comment: yet it is already covered by that answer (and others)