# I'm to calculate the tag, index and offset for a given setup

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, cache

Total Memory size = 65,536 bytes
Number of cache blocks = 32 cache blocks
Cache size = total 512 bytes

So using this info provided I cannot figure out how to calculate the cache block number.
I know if number of cache blocks =2^M then the last M bits is the cache index. But how to calculate the block number? and then finally calculate the bits required for tag index and offset..

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER SCIENCE @SE. Is *the block number* something other than *Number of cache blocks*? If *yes*, I think I'd need to consider *mapping*: To what *address mappings* have you been introduced?

Comment: check https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43876/157